# Invalid argument to function error in ms access in correlated subquery

Tags: ms-access, correlated-subquery

I have a problem in my correlated subquery in ms access.
Here is my query :

```
SELECT t1.MfgProductId,
   (SELECT Sum(BalanceQuantity)
       FROM qry_MfgShipmentDetailWIP AS t2
       WHERE t2.MfgProductId = t1.MfgProductId) AS PrevQty
   FROM qry_MfgShipmentDetailWIP AS t1;
```

But when i run this i get error : invalid argument to a function.
But when i run like this :

```
SELECT t1.MfgProductId,
   (SELECT Sum(BalanceQuantity)
       FROM qry_MfgShipmentDetailWIP AS t2
       WHERE t2.MfgProductId = 'CFC1C06') AS PrevQty
   FROM qry_MfgShipmentDetailWIP AS t1;
```

It runs fine.

Please help what causes the error?

Error while running the query in ms access sql view:

[image: Error while running a query in ms access sql view]

Comment: I'not very familiar with MS specific SQL, but I guess it's a matter of the scope in which you can use alias names (like `t1`) of database objects. Try this: `WHERE t2.MfgProductId = qry_MfgShipmentDetailWIP.MfgProductId`

Comment: I am unable to recreate the issue using Access 2010. Your first query does not produce any errors for me.

Comment: Where are you getting the error? As @GordThompson says - the SQL is not the issue. Are you running code?

Comment: Query doesn't make much sense to me - can't you just get the result you want with the inner query if you group by product id?

Comment: @JimHawkins i have tried but same error.

Comment: Perhaps the error is in `qry_MfgShipmentDetailWIP`, but it happens only for certain rows, not for `'CFC1C06'`. If you use any kind of functions in there, please add its SQL to the question.